# Messing up the event handler in django, help me figure it out

Tags: django, web, django-rest-framework

My models:

```
class Product(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
        owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='owner')
        allowed_users = models.ManyToManyField(User)
    
    
        def __str__(self):
            return self.name
    
    
    class Lesson(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
        link = models.URLField()
        time = models.PositiveIntegerField()
        products = models.ManyToManyField(Product)
    
        def __str__(self):
            return self.name
    
    
    class UserLessons(models.Model):
        user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
        lesson = models.ForeignKey(Lesson, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
        is_view = models.BooleanField(default=False)
        view_time = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
        date_view = models.DateField(null=True)
    
        def __str__(self):
            return f'{self.user.username} - {self.lesson.name}
```

I am implementing an event handler that should create a record in the DB when creating a Lesson record

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Lesson)
def create_user_lessons(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    products = instance.products.all()
    allowed_users = []
    for product in products:
        for user in product.allowed_users.all():
            if user not in allowed_users:
                allowed_users.append(user)
    for user in allowed_users:
        UserLessons.objects.create(user=user, lesson=instance)
```

But I came across the fact that `instance.products.all()` outputs an empty QuerySet, although it is not empty when creating a record. What is the reason for this behavior and how to solve it?

I tried to redefine the `save()` method, but it didn't help in any way, but an important clarification appeared, `instance.products.all()` gives an empty qs only for the record that was created at the moment, the rest of the records work fully, when choosing another, everything is saved as needed

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is wait for the model to send the boolean `created` to the receiver and then you can write your logic. That said, your code should look like:

```py
@receiver(post_save, sender=Lesson)
def create_user_lessons(sender, created, instance, **kwargs):
    if created:
        allowed_users = set()
        for product in instance.products.all():
            for user in product.allowed_users.all():
                allowed_users.add(user)
        for user in allowed_users:
            UserLessons.objects.create(user=user, lesson=instance)
    return instance
```

Comment: The problem has not been solved, created returns True, but products does not see it as before